# Array not containing values when using "in_array" (php) w/ mysql_query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I continue to struggle with array! This is probably easy to answer.

I'm retrieving a data set from MYSQL w/ PHP. I get an array that has the 1st row (ala the mysql_fetch_array). Typically I would just loop through this and get each value, but in this case I'm already in the middle of a loop and I need to find out if a particular value exists in the full data set (which will be more than 1 row).

I figured I could just loop through and put all the values into an array with something like:

```
$query = "SELECT MapId FROM Map Where GameId = $gl_game_id";
$result_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
confirm_query($result_set);     
$map_set = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
    $map_set[] = $row;
}
```

When I print_r this, I do in fact get the full data set (e.g. all rows of MapId from table Map).

So now, when I go to look in there and see if a value (that is coming out of this other loop) exists, it won't find it.

So my code looks like:

```
if (in_array($i, $map_set)) {
    echo "yes, it's there baby!";       
}
```

But it doesn't work. I tried hard coding the array, and that does in fact work. So there is simply something wrong with the way I'm constructing my array that this function doesn't like it.

```
if (in_array($i, array(40,12,53,65))) {
    echo "yes, it's there baby!";       
}
```

arrrg... I do hate being a noobie at this.

Comment: what's the structure of your $map_set array, could you post that as well..

Comment: BTW, the mysql extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension

Comment: @Jeff - We must see your $map_set structure first to help you out with this :P

Comment: @Sudhir yes, I know, I haven't made the switch, but will do it. Thanks. The solution from the response worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function mysql_fetch_assoc returned array.

If you make print_r($map_set) then you will see that is 2-dimension array. Sure in_array not worked.

Just replace `$map_set[] = $row;` by `$map_set[] = $row["MapId"];` and then try again.

Comment: I KNEW it was simple! Thank you so much!